# Getting error when creating a view from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database, tableview

I have to create a view in MySQL, this is the code:

```
CREATE VIEW dashboard_sales AS (
    SELECT o.order_id,o.order_date,o.order_status,op.op_status,oi.oi_qty 
    FROM
        order o
    LEFT JOIN
        order_items oi
    ON
        o.order_id = oi.order_id
    LEFT JOIN
        order_payment op
    ON 
        o.order_id = op.order_id
    GROUP BY o.order_id
);
```

but when I execute in phpmyadmin, I get an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o
>           LEFT JOIN
>               order_items oi
>           ON
>               o.order_id = oi.' at line 4

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the parentheses in your create view statement.  Are you certain that this code really ran on MySQL without any errors?

Comment: [`order`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O) is one of the reserved keyword in MySQL. Rename the table name to non-reserved keyword or escape it with back tick `\``. Also `GROUP BY` is working with any aggregate function like `MAX(), COUNT(), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a backtick for `order`

```
CREATE VIEW dashboard_sales AS (
    SELECT o.order_id,o.order_date,o.order_status,op.op_status,oi.oi_qty 
    FROM `order` o LEFT JOIN order_items oi
    ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
    LEFT JOIN order_payment op
    ON o.order_id = op.order_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the keywords for the name of the tables, you should place the table between the Brackets.

```
CREATE VIEW dashboard_sales AS (
SELECT o.order_id,o.order_date,o.order_status,op.op_status,oi.oi_qty 
FROM
    [order] o
LEFT JOIN
    order_items oi
ON
    o.order_id = oi.order_id
LEFT JOIN
    order_payment op
ON 
    o.order_id = op.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

);